# What is SystemJS config.js map?

Tags: bundling-and-minification, aurelia, jspm, systemjs

Using jspm 0.16.13, I've noticed that in addition to mapping "a module alias to a location or package" `config.js` `map` also seems to be defining a module's dependencies. For example, see the snippet below. However, in this particular example, at least on my generated config.js, this module doesn't appear anywhere else in the `map`.

```
"github:aurelia/logging-console@0.7.1": {
  "aurelia-logging": "github:aurelia/logging@0.7.0"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a "vendor" bundle using `jspm`... put all "third party" dependencies into it's own bundle. I need to manually list the modules because I'm using aurelia---including the "main aurelia module" won't automagically include it's dependencies. (That's probably true of other libraries as well.)

Can someone explain `config.js` `map`? Or provide a better way to list all of an app's dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bundle arithmetic to bundle your app dependencies into a vendor.js:

```
jspm bundle app/**/* - [app/**/*] vendor.js
```

Explanation of the syntax by Guy Bedford: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1109#issuecomment-141385673

An alternative solution is to bundle all modules listed in the package.json:

https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1109#issuecomment-139529178

As for the `map`, it defines aliases (or dependencies, does not really matter) so that import statements can refer to a module using a short name. In the future, it will be possible to import a module using an URL.

Comment: You're saying that if I use the dependencies listed in package.json, that should be enough?  I think I tried that and there were modules that were unbundled. Think it might be an aurelia thing. seems that config.js gives a more complete dependency list

Comment: if aurelia mangles config.js on its own it's possible that there is some extra content in config.js. But why does not it use jspm?